# Unable to convert Data to JSON from API Request - stackoverflow api

Tags: swift, api, nsurlsession, urlsession

I am trying to do a get request using the stackoverflow api using URLSession but i keep getting the following error:

**The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.sendsWholeSearchString = true

    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=swift&filter=default&site=stackoverflow") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            //handle response here
            if let error = error {
                print("Fuck! \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

I already have the url set to get `swift` results as if from a search so the url is "https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=swift&filter=default&site=stackoverflow"

Also I read that the data is normally a gzip format but found that apparently URLSession automatically handles it ..

Any suggestions on where i am going wrong?

Comment: API is returning HTML instead of a JSON. You can verify this by printing as `print(String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)`.

Comment: @Kamran how can i make it return a json instead then? is the url i added wrong?

Comment: just enter your url in a webbrowser - the answer will surprise you ;)

Comment: You can not make it. Find a valid url that returns a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The correct url i was suppose to be using was https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=swift&site=stackoverflow

instead of

"https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=swift&filter=default&site=stackoverflow"

Comment: Yea! All set now

Answer (score 0):

check it on postman this API returns HTML that's why you got HTML.